# Getting type from new classes copied at runtime returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, types

On a button push, my webapp copies several classes in to the project and then checks if the new files contain a class named my.namespace.myclass with Type.GetType("my.namespace.myclass", false, true);
This returns null even though i can see the class with correct namespace, and if I write my.namespace.myclass inside my code(after refreshing files inside VS), the class is usable. If i click the same button again, the type is now found; i am guessing the class were not compiled before, but it is now.

Is there some way to force compile the files before trying to get the type? I tried restarting the asp.net application programmatically, but the type is still null.

Any help appreciated

Comment: .cs files are not classes - they are just files. Until you do a compile on them, they aren't executable code.
Maybe you could get those classes in another project, and compile that project to produce an assembly?

Comment: that is true, but I kind of thought they got compiled instantly when placing them inside app_code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. What I understand is that you want to load a text file (.cs file are basicly text files) and use reflaction on the code inside it.

If I understand you correctly then you need to do some runtime compiling. It's not all that complicated, but still needs to be done. You can use the instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codecompilation.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you drop files into App_Code they are compiled into a separate assembly, and will cause your web app to recompile.  The problem is, if you are copying them into App_Code, you won't see when you do Type.GetType(...) because your *current* version of App_Code (the compiled version currently running) doesn't contain them.  I'd recommend trying to deliver them a separate way. App_Code is a special mechanism in ASP.NET, I wouldn't rely on this for practical applications.  I'd rather have the classes compiled and dropped into another folder, where I can load them into the AppDomain and reflect where I need to.